# How to paint each group of chart points by a different color?

Tags: excel, plot

I have a series of x,y and c data in excel for example:

x=[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8]

y=[0 1.7 2.6 4.5 7.3 8.9 9.6 9.9]

t=[1 1 1 1 2 2 3 4]

I plotted y versus x in excel. I want to paint the points by different colors based on the t values. For example the 4 initial points have the same t value (t=1) and should have the same color, or the points with t=2 another color, and so.
I am searching for an automated method because in real case I have hundreds of points. Also, I can't use conditional formatting in excel because the t values have not a certain trend.

Comment: Short answer: This is possible. Long answer is that you'll need VBA knowledge and then it's fairly straight forward. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Use **Format as table** for your main data.
2. Create a pivot table on base of that table.
3. Put in **Rows -> x**, **Columns -> t**, **Values -. y**.
4. Select any cell in the pivot table, go to **Insert** tab, and insert a **Line with Markers** chart.
5. Select each marker in the chart and go to **Format** tab. There select **No outline** in **Shape Outline**.
6. Add all the data that you want and refresh the pivot table :D

[image]